# Error on video recording in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, video

I played with the AVCam demo sample in order to add a player (MPMoviePlayerController) that allows the preview of the recorded video

I added a play button in the xib and the corresponding IBOutlet and IBActions + a player:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *playerButton;
@property (nonatomic, assign) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender;
```

I do initialize the player in the viewdidload:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
```

the play Action is as follows

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {

     if(player) {
     [player stop];
     }
     // Create a new movie player object.
     [player setContentURL:[[[self captureManager] recorder] outputFileURL]];
     player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 200, 300);
    // Inset the movie frame in the parent view frame.
    [[player view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];

    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    //player.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

    //[self.view addSubview: [_player view]];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

    if(player) {
    [player play];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playComplete) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

}
```

and the playComplete called when play is finished:

```
-(void)playComplete {
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

result:
When I launch the app, I can record as many videos as I want.
when I play the last recorded video, I can play it without problems
but after playing the video, if i try to record again, I encounter this error as soon as it starts recording:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11803 "Cannot Record" UserInfo=0x152e60 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again., AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record}

i thought it was a problem on the temp output file, but it seems not.

I'm wondering if introducing a MPMoviePlayerController breaks the behavior of the app in some way that I cannot figure out.

do some of you have any idea?

Thanks

P

Answer (score 2):

found that the -11803 was due to the fact that the captureManager session was not running (found the answer on Stackoverflow but i did not understand it very fast...)

at the end of the video preview play, in playComplete, I added a test to check the capture manager session status, to make it run if this was not the case anymore.

```
-(void)playComplete {
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    if(![[[self captureManager] session] isRunning]) {
        // Start the session. This is done asychronously since -startRunning doesn't return until the session is running.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [[[self captureManager] session] startRunning];
        });
    }
}
```

It is working now, but if anyone knows why the video preview stops the captureManager session, I would be happy to understand it.

P